pricing option with two volatility regimes
How would I price a 1-year ATM European call option, given I know that for the first 6 months, the realized volatility will be 20% and the latter six months, the realized volatilty will be 90%?
One estimation is computing the vega pnl at the six month mark when we remark the option from 20% to 90%. But this relies on an assumption about the spot price. Is there an actual solution to this problem without making too many assumptions?

Just use a time dependent instantaneous volatility?

The implied vol should be the sqrt of realised variance over the option.
This is $sqrt(0.5*(20)^2+0.5*(90)^2)$.
This is just a result of the fact that for a European option, only the terminal distribution matters, so the vol of the terminal distribution determines everything.
Edit: You don't need to make any assumption, option is priced by the information you have provided.

thanks - think general integral is: integral_(t0 to t) of sigma^2(s) ds / (t-t0)
